# what is wrong with this call to the java method?

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface, jnienv

I am trying to call a Java method from the code. C code listens to either `Escape`, `Shift`, `Ctrl` key press, then it calls the Java method telling which key was pressed. Following are the snippets that play a role in this.

*C Snippet:*

```
mid = (*env)->GetMethodID(env,cls,"callBack","(Ljava/lang/String;)V");
Env = env;
if(called)
    switch(param) {
        case VK_CONTROL:
            printf("Control pressed !\n");
            (*Env)->CallVoidMethodA(Env,Obj,mid,"11"); // calling the java method
            break;
        case VK_SHIFT:
            printf("Shift pressed !\n");
            (*Env)->CallVoidMethodA(Env,Obj,mid,"10"); // calling the java method
            break;
        case VK_ESCAPE:
            printf("Escape pressed !\n");
            (*Env)->CallVoidMethodA(Env,Obj,mid,"1B"); // calling the java method
            break;
        default:
            printf("The default case\n");
            break;
    }
```

*Java Snippet:*

```
public void callBack(String key) {
    String x = KeyEvent.getKeyText(Integer.parseInt(key, 16));
    System.out.println(x);
}
```

When I run the program and press the `Escape` key I get this on the console:

```
Escape pressed !
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x5c8b809a, pid=7588, tid=8088
#
# JRE version: 7.0
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (20.0-b01 mixed mode, sharing windows-x86 )
# Problematic frame:
# V  [jvm.dll+0x19809a]
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# W:\UnderTest\NetbeansCurrent\KeyLoggerTester\build\classes\hs_err_pid7588.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport/crash.jsp
#
```

I know I am calling the Java function the wrong way, but I don't know where I am wrong. As from the output, it satisfies the case when I press the `Escape` key and then an unexpected error occurs.

[*Link to the LOG FILE*](http://suhail03.my3gb.com/hs_err_pid7852.log)

**EDIT:**

After the answer by [mavroprovato](https://stackoverflow.com/users/89435/mavroprovato) I still get the same errors.

I edited this way:

```
(*Env)->CallVoidMethodA(Env,Obj,mid,(*Env)->NewStringUTF(Env,"1B"));
```

**EDIT:**

### [COMPLETE CODE version 1](http://programworks.co.cc/complete%20code.html)

### [COMPLETE CODE version 2](http://programworks.co.cc/bummers/crash.html)

Comment: You are missing the `break` for the Escape-case, by the way.

Comment: Can you create a minimal test-case?

Comment: Post W:\UnderTest\NetbeansCurrent\KeyLoggerTester\build\classes\hs_err_pid7588.log

Comment: Is the problem the parameter you are passing to your Java method? Your method needs a java.lang.String, but you're passing a C string like "1B" and I'm not sure that is compatible.

Comment: @Rob Kielty [Here is the log file](http://suhail03.my3gb.com/hs_err_pid7852.log)

Comment: How do you attach to the JVM from your C code? I guess that this is from a C callback and then you will have to access the JVM through `AttachCurrentThread()`. But since we don't see all your code it is quite difficult. The `JNIEnv` pointer cannot be cached for example.

Comment: @maba what is the point in telling `JNIENv` cannot be cached ? Is this step `Env=env`  wrong ?

Comment: We don't see the code you are using in your callback. The `JNIEnv` pointer cannot be cached between different threads. Where did you get hold of the `env` (not the `Env`) pointer in your snippet? And how did you get hold of your `Obj` reference?

Comment: In your `initializeJNIVars` you are caching the `env` pointer which is not allowed! Your `LowLevelKeyboardProc` is most likely running in another thread and then you will have to use the `AttachCurrenThread()` method to get hold on the `JNIEnv`. And the `Obj` reference must be made global.

Comment: @maba can you please explain this in detail in your answer. I don't exactly get it

Comment: JNI coding is quite complex. You have to be aware of some pitfalls and especially when dealing with multiple threads. I just pointed out some _low hanging fruit_ in my answer. My advice is that you read the [JNI Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/jniTOC.html) for details. I could add some more stuff in my answer but then on the other hand I would probably do most of your coding and that is probably not meaningful (at least not to me). I will see if I can add some more code anyway.

Comment: You could maybe up-vote my answer since that is anyway the answer to why you have the JVM crash.

Comment: Why are you using `CallVoidMethodA`, I would think that `CallVoidMethod` will do

Comment: @jogabonito how can you pass an argument using that?

Comment: [link] (http://journals.ecs.soton.ac.uk/java/tutorial/native1.1/implementing/method.html)   In your case it will be something like `CallVoidMethod(env, obj, mid, myJString)`   Anyway this needn't be the cause of the crash. It looks to the env problem. Have a look at my answer below

Comment: CallVoidMethodV is for a variable arguments list and CallVoidMethodA  is expecting some sort of a union

Comment: @jogabonito can't i pass a string using `callVoidMethodA()` ?

Comment: In the link I shared, there is a section "Passing Arguments to Java Methods" with a description of  `callVoidMethodA`. I haven't fully understood it, but I dont think it is the method you are looking for. I am sure that `callVoidMethod` works. Is there any special reason why you want to use `callVoidMethodA`

Comment: @jogabonito i want to pass arguments to the java method defined.And to me `CallVoidMethodA` should work fine

Comment: Your code, your decisions :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The JVM is crashing because the `JNIEnv` that is used is not a valid one. There are other issues with the code as well.

The [Sun JNI documentation](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jni/html/other.html) is providing very good information regarding threads.

Here comes some parts that are obvious:

Create a `JNI_OnLoad` function in your code. It will be called when the library is loaded. Then cache the `JavaVM` pointer because that is valid across threads. An alternative is to call `(*env)->GetJavaVM` in the `initializeJNIVars` function but I prefer the first one.

In your `initializeJNIVars` you can save the `obj` reference by calling `Obj = (*env)->NewGlobalRef(obj)`.

In the `LowLevelKeyboardProc` you will have to get the `env` pointer:

`AttachCurrentThread(JavaVM *jvm, JNIEnv &env, NULL);`

---

**Edit**

OK, here are the code that you should add to get it working, I have tried it myself and it works. **NB**: I have not analyzed what your code is actually doing so I just did some fixes to get it working.

Add these variables among your other global variables:

```
static JavaVM *javaVM = NULL;
static jmethodID callbackMethod = NULL;
static jobject callbackObject = NULL;
```

You can remove your `cls`, `mid`, `Env` and  `Obj` variables and use mine instead.

Create the JNI_OnLoad method where you cache the JavaVM pointer:

```
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL JNI_OnLoad(JavaVM *jvm, void *reserved) {
    JNIEnv *env = 0;

    if ((*jvm)->GetEnv(jvm, (void**)&env, JNI_VERSION_1_4)) {
        return JNI_ERR;
    }

    javaVM = jvm;

    return JNI_VERSION_1_4;
}
```

Alter your `initializeJNIVars` to look like the following:

```
void Java_keylogger_TestKeys_initializeJNIVars(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj) {
    jclass cls = (*env)->GetObjectClass(env,obj);
    callbackMethod = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, cls, "callBack", "(Ljava/lang/String;)V");
    callbackObject = (*env)->NewGlobalRef(env, obj);
    if(cls == NULL || callbackMethod == NULL) {
        printf("One of them is null \n");
    }
    called = TRUE;
}
```

And finally in your `LowLoevelKeyboardProc` code you will have to add the following:

```
...
WPARAM param = kbhook->vkCode;

JNIEnv *env;
jint rs = (*javaVM)->AttachCurrentThread(javaVM, (void**)&env, NULL);
if (rs != JNI_OK) {
    return NULL; // Or something appropriate...
}
...

    case VK_ESCAPE:
        printf("Escape pressed !\n");
        jstring message = (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, "1B");
        (*env)->CallVoidMethod(env, callbackObject, callbackMethod, message);
        break;
...
```

In your `unregisterWinHook` you should delete the global reference so that objects can be GC'd.

```
...
(*env)->DeleteGlobalRef(env, callbackObject);
```

And that's it.

Comment: [i am getting errors on modifying like this](http://i50.tinypic.com/fxdwzl.jpg). Here are the [errors](http://i48.tinypic.com/a9l5hh.jpg)

Comment: Sorry. My bad. Since you are not using c++ you have to pass env as first parameter then the others.

Comment: like this : `env = (*jvm)->AttachCurrentThread(void( **)&env,jvm,NULL);` ? Getting the same errors

Comment: You have to check the api documentation. I will help you soon. Have to get on a train...

Comment: what is wrong with initializing `Obj` in the `initializeJNIVars` ? It doesn't act as a global var ?

Comment: Yes it does. You have defined it globally in your c-module and it is initialized in `initializeJNIVars` and then you use it in `LowLevelKeyboardProc`. If you don't call `NewGlobalRef` then the JVM can remove it when it runs the GC.

Comment: [my jvm crashes when it enters this case statement](http://i46.tinypic.com/2dw8fme.jpg) what could be the problem ?

Comment: Though i have not tried your code yet,but have applied the methods/procedures you told me.[I have uploaded the code here,which still crashes my jvm when i press the escape key.](http://programworks.co.cc/bummers/crash.html) The call sequences are the same old one. Look exclusively for the `escape` case in the code

Comment: You are not supposed to create a new JVM!!! You are running in a JVM so why create a new???????

Comment: first what does creating a jvm means exactly ? I did this to get the `env` in the _escape_ case block.`env = (*jvm)->AttachCurrentThread(jvm,&env,NULL);`

Comment: Are you and @program-o-steve the same person? It looks like you just posted a question regarding since the code for creating the JVM looks EXACTLY the same: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10943698/initializing-the-third-argument-of-jni-createjavavm.

Comment: Please, look at my example and you will see how to store the JVM pointer.

Comment: but can you please answer "what does creating a jvm means exactly"

Comment: finally able to call the function. But i still don't know what does creating a jvm using `JNI_CreateJavaVM` mean ? what mistake was i actually committing in the code [I gave here](http://programworks.co.cc/bummers/crash.html)?

Comment: [This link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/invocation.html) will tell you more about the Invocation API. Read it.

Answer (score 3):

I believe you cannot call a java method that takes a String parameter and pass it a `char*`. You should call [NewStringUTF](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jni/spec/functions.html#wp17220) first.

Comment: Then please post the pid log file that is generated

Answer (score 0):

I think it is due to the UAC feature enabled on your Operating System. This was a bug for Java 6. Read [this](http://java.com/en/download/help/exception_access.xml) for further reference.

The reason I say this is because the event to the escape key is fired correctly and the problem only begins as soon as the call to the java method is done.