# jvm crashes as soon as I press escape

Tags: java, c, multithreading, java-native-interface

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [what is wrong with this call to the java method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10895826/what-is-wrong-with-this-call-to-the-java-method)

The following C snippet calls a java function whenever the escape key is pressed. The first block of C snippet executes on a different thread and second block executes on a different thread.When i press the escape key,the message `escape key pressed` is displayed and then the jvm crashes.Why doesn't the java function get called ?

*C Code :*

```
    if(called) {// starts on a different thread
    switch(param) {
        case VK_CONTROL:
            printf("Control pressed !\n");
            //(*Env)->CallVoidMethodA(Env,Obj,mid,"11");
            break;
        case VK_SHIFT:
            printf("Shift pressed !\n");
            //(*Env)->CallVoidMethodA(Env,Obj,mid,"10");
            break;
        case VK_ESCAPE:
            printf("Escape pressed !\n");
            JavaVM *jvm;
            JNIEnv *env;
            jmethodID mid;
            env = (*jvm)->AttachCurrentThread(jvm,&env,NULL);
            jclass cls = (*env)->GetObjectClass(env,Obj);
            mid = (*env)->GetMethodID(env,cls,"callBack","(Ljava/lang/String;)V");
            (*env)->CallVoidMethodA(env,Obj,mid,(*env)->NewStringUTF(env,"1B")); // Calling the java function
            break;
        default:
            printf("The default case\n");
            break;
    }}

    void Java_keylogger_TestKeys_initializeJNIVars
     (JNIEnv *env, jobject obj) { // starts on a different thread

      Obj = (*env)->NewGlobalRef(env,obj);
      if(Obj == NULL) {
        printf("Obj is Null\n");
      }
      called = TRUE;
   }
```

*Java Snippet :*

```
    public void callBack(String key) {
      String x = KeyEvent.getKeyText(Integer.parseInt(key, 16));
      System.out.println(x);
    }
```

[I have uploaded the complete code with the output here.](http://programworks.co.cc/bummers/TestKeys.html)

Comment: the most obvious ones are jvm and env in the switch pointing to nowhere.

Comment: I have been answering this question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10895826/what-is-wrong-with-this-call-to-the-java-method/10896756#10896756 Why are you posting the same question again????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to initialize your `jvm` variable. You can do this using `JNI_CreateJavaVM()`method. See here for more information: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/jni/spec/invocation.html

Comment: and how can i initialize the third argument _(vm_args)_ in this method ? The link you have given in the answer,is too old. The struct `JDK1_1InitArgs`  mentioned in the link has been removed from the header file.

Comment: I checked the jni.h in the JDK1.7 and there is the struct `JavaVMInitArgs`. I guess this one replaces the older one. See <JDK_HOME>\include\jni.h in your computer for further details.