# initializing the third argument of JNI_CreateJavaVM

Tags: java, java-native-interface

The third argument of the method `JNI_CreateJavaVM` takes the third argument as `JavaVMInitArgs` structure.

```
typedef struct JavaVMInitArgs { 
                     jint version; 
                     jint nOptions; 
                     JavaVMOption *options; 
                     jboolean ignoreUnrecognized; 
                 } JavaVMInitArgs;
```

How do i initialize this ? I am unable to do so.

**Prototype of JNI_CreateJavaVM**: `jint JNI_CreateJavaVM(JavaVM **pvm, void **penv, 
                         void *vm_args);`

How do i initialize vm_args ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*After some discussion we came to the conclution that you had problems with your compiler setup.*

To be able to successfully compile and link `JNI_CreateJavaVM` you need to add the `jvm` library to your linker.

---

### Initial answer:

Looking at [The Invocation API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jni/spec/invocation.html) the following example might explain what you need to do:

```
JavaVMInitArgs vm_args;
JavaVMOption options[4];

options[0].optionString = "-Djava.compiler=NONE";           /* disable JIT */
options[1].optionString = "-Djava.class.path=c:\myclasses"; /* user classes */
options[2].optionString = "-Djava.library.path=c:\mylibs";  /* set native library path */
options[3].optionString = "-verbose:jni";                   /* print JNI-related messages */

vm_args.version = JNI_VERSION_1_2;
vm_args.options = options;
vm_args.nOptions = 4;
vm_args.ignoreUnrecognized = TRUE;

/* Note that in the JDK, there is no longer any need to call 
 * JNI_GetDefaultJavaVMInitArgs. 
 */
res = JNI_CreateJavaVM(&vm, (void **)&env, &vm_args);
if (res < 0) ...
```

Comment: [when i did this,i get an error :](http://i50.tinypic.com/2ugma6t.jpg) saying `W:\elita\jnitesters\workspace\c\MyHook\MyHook.c|57|undefined reference to _imp__JNI_CreateJavaVM@12'|` [error message](http://i48.tinypic.com/15fkcxj.jpg)

Comment: I think your include directories are not set up correctly (check that you include both `jdk/include` and `jdk/include/<platform>`).

Comment: where should i include them ?

Comment: Your compiler options, and while you are checking your options, also check that your library path and your `-D_JNI_IMPLEMENTATION_` variables are set for the linker.

Comment: i have been running jni programs for a month now in the same manner. Why do you think that there is a include problem ?

Comment: Ah, then you probably don't have any problems with that. How did the code look before you ran into this problem?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12288/discussion-between-dacwe-and-program-o-steve)

Comment: [comment the statement `JNI_CreateJavaVM(&jvm, &env, &vm_args);` and the code is compiled without the errors](http://i.stack.imgur.com/uScbK.jpg)

Comment: options[1].optionString = "-Djava.class.path=c:\myclasses"; Am i Have to give .jar file location? When I compiled I got .class files